# Query takes extremely too long to execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch all the courses that a student has from a MySQL database. This snippet only fetches 1 course, but there are 6 in total (and then it takes 15 seconds). I'm trying to display the course that is already has been set (if any) by using the `selected` attribute in the `option` tag. I think this is what causes the query to execute for so long.
Is something wrong with my database design? How do I improve the query?

This is the database's structure. I created an intermediary table **user_courses**:

**users**:
user_id

**users_courses**:
user_id
course_id_1
course_id_2
course_id_3
course_id_4
course_id_5
course_id_6
course_id_7

**courses**:
course_id
course_name

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
    require ('../mysqli_connect.php');

    echo '<table><tr><td><select name="course_id_1">';

    // checking if a user has already chosen a 1st course (out of 6)
    $query = "SELECT c.course_id
              FROM courses AS c
              INNER JOIN users_courses AS u
              ON c.course_id = u.course_id_1
              WHERE u.user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    // if yes, assign the selected course from the database to a variable
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $selected_course = $row['course_id'];
    }

    // fetch courses, and make 'None' the first option in the drop down menu
    $query = "SELECT course_id, course_name 
              FROM courses 
              ORDER BY (course_name = 'None') DESC, course_name";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    // create the drop down menu
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // select default value
        if ($selected_course == $row['course_id']) {
            $selected =' selected';
        } else {
            $selected='';
        }

        echo '<option value="' . $row['course_id'] . '"' . $selected . '>'
              . htmlspecialchars($row['course_name']) . '</option>';
    }

    echo '</select></td></tr>';

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($dbc); 
?>
```

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: I don't have any in this snippet.

Comment: Get some profiling, t know how much time take connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of problems here.

1) Your explanation of your table structure isn't sufficient to diagnose some common problems like missing indexes, or what you've established as a primary key. Those choices can have dramatic impacts on performance.

2) Your `users_courses` table is denormalized; a more common way to model many-to-many relationships is to have a table with one foreign key for each of the joined tables. In that case, your table would look like:

```
USERS_COURSES
-------------
user_id
course_id
```

And then a user with 7 courses would have 7 records in that table. If it's actually important to your model to know priorities like "first choice", you could extend the join table with an appropriate column.

3) Your PHP code is wide open for [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/info) because you're directly interpolating user input into your query. You need to fix that and adopt a practice of always using bind variables

Comment: Why is it open of SQL injection attacks? I'm not entering any text data.

Comment: You're taking stuff the user gives you (from the `$_SESSION`) variable and passing it straight to the database server. Read the link @Palpatim has provided.

Answer (score 1):

try this ... this creates the indexes, that jeff mentioned

```
CREATE INDEX _index_course ON courses(course_id);
CREATE INDEX _index_user_course ON users_courses(course_id_1);
```